# prevent resize column from shrinking other columns

Tags: html, css

How can I use `resize` and specify a `min-width` for a table.

It seems when specifying any sort of `min-width` attribute for the table then the table will never resize beyond that specified value. I would like for the table to scale wider than the screen width and keep growing beyond that. Instead what happens is the other columns shrink to accommodate the new larger column.

Specifying a min-width on the columns causes the resize to stop working.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  min-width: 200%;
}

th {
  resize: horizontal;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>AAA</th>
    <th>BBB</th>
    <th>CCC</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>four</td>
    <td>five</td>
    <td>six</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>seven</td>
    <td>eight</td>
    <td>nine</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I already tried to wrap the table in a `<div style="overflow:scroll">` but that didn't prevent to column crushing from happening.

Comment: It's because you have the `<table>`'s width set to a `%` value, so if any column is made smaller then the other columns **have to** be made wider to ensure the `<table>` stays the same width. You'll need to add a new placeholder column to the end that is set to always expand to fill available space, though I'm unsure how best to do that.

Comment: _"I would like for the table to scale wider than the screen width and keep growing beyond that."_ - keep growing, based on - _what_? Your table cells do not have content that _demands_ them to be any wider. So why should the browser be inclined to make this table any wider than that min-width of 200% you specified?

Comment: Another option, is to use JS to remove the `%` width from the `<table>` once the user starts to resize any columns.

Comment: @CBroe keep growing based on the user dragging the column and wanting to resize them wider.

Comment: The width of your columns is determined by the overall width of the table being divided up between them. When you increase the width of that first column via dragging - then there is still enough space left in all the other columns for them to _shrink_, so that the overall sum will be a 200% wide table again. I don't think there is a way to achieve what you want using CSS alone.